# Android Bluetooth pairing intent

Tags: android, bluetooth

I use the following code in an onItemClickListener

```
            BluetoothDevice device;
        device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent("android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST");
        intent1.putExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE", device);
        intent1.putExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_VARIANT", 0);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent1);
```

It opens the pairing dialog where the user enters the pin, but it doesn't actually pair.

A very similar question has been asked before, but nobody answered it, hopefully I'll have more luck

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you still have this problem since this question is really old, but I'm doing an app which does exactly this, so I'll share my code for pairing:

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
device = bluetooth.getRemoteDevice(address);

// Opens the pin dialog and then bonds the device
device.createBond();
```

Hopefully it will help somebody.